# Linear regression with loss function $\frac{y|(\hat{y}-y)|}{max(\hat{y}, y)}$

Tags: regression, optimization

I have a linear regression problem with loss function something like this

$L=\sum_i\frac{y_i|\hat{y}_i-y_i|}{max(\hat{y}_i, y_i)}$,

in which $\hat{y}_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{1i}+\beta_2x_{2i}+\cdots+\beta_nx_{ni}$ is the $i$th predicted value and $y_i$ is the $i$th true value. The true value $y_i$ is guarenteed to be nonnegative.

Does anyone know how I can minimize the loss function to get the coefficients $\beta_0, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_n$?